# Combinations of integers

Tags: java, combinations

I'd appreciate any help on the following problem. I have n integers from 0 to n-1, and I'm trying to generate a list of all possible combinations of length k (i.e. k concatenated integers) such that every pair of consecutive integers are not equal. So, for example, (1)(2)(3)(2) would be valid with k = 4, but (1)(2)(3)(3) would not be valid. Any ideas on how to approach this most efficiently? (I don't care much about length/degree of complexity of the code, just efficiency)

Comment: @A. R. S.: what Louis Wasserman probably meant with 'what have you tried' is: show us the code (and tell us what doesn't work specifically).

Comment: Actually, it looks more like he's trying to brute-force an unlock-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the code:

```
    void Generate(int[] source, List<int[]> result, int[] build, int k, int num) {
      if (num == k) {
        int[] a = (int[])build.clone();
        result.add(a);
        return;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
        if (num == 0 || source[i] != build[num - 1])
        {
          build[num] = source[i];
          Generate(source, result, build, k, num + 1);
        }
    }
```

How to call:

```
    int k = 2;
    List<int[]> a = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    Generate(new int[]{1,2,3}, a, new int[k], k, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void recursiveOutput(Integer n, int k, int limit, String prints){
    k++;
    if(k>limit)
        return;
    String statePrints = prints;
            //cycle through all available numbers
    for(Integer i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        statePrints = prints;
                    //First cycle
        if(k==1){
            statePrints+= "(" + i.toString() + ")";
            recursiveOutput(n, k, limit, statePrints);
        }
                    //check if predecessor is not the same
        if(i != Integer.parseInt(statePrints.substring(statePrints.length()-2,statePrints.length()-1))){
            statePrints += "(" + i.toString() + ")";
            recursiveOutput(n, k, limit, statePrints);
        }
    }
            //Check if the length matches the combination length
    if(statePrints.length() == 3 * limit)
    System.out.println(statePrints);
}
```

call :`recursiveOutput(3,0,4,"");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Generator {
    final int k = 2;
    final char[] n = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    final char[] text = new char[k];

    public void gen(int i, int not_n) {
        if(i == k) {
            System.out.println(text);
            return;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < n.length; j++) {
            if(j == not_n) continue;
            text[i] = n[j];
            gen(i+1, j);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Generator().gen(0, -1);
    }
```

}